# Microsoft Visual Studio Code do not start

Tags: visual-studio-code

I installed the program, but it starts and does not draw the entire interface. I do not even know how to describe the problem. Here is a screenshot.
 Thanks for the answer, I do not even know in which direction to solve the problem.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: the screenshot is just blank.

Comment: that's right, no interface elements. I reinstalled the program, but the problem persists